# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using the jquery datepicker and i am calling a custom function with the name customRange.

Without this function datepicker works absolutely fine.

With the function running i am getting an error at the point :

```
if ($("#EndDate").datepicker("getDate") != null) {
```

"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'"

Why is this happening?

```
    $('#StartDate, #EndDate').datepicker({
        //dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        hourMin: 9,
        hourMax: 17,
        //minDate: '0',
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        beforeShow: customRange,
        firstDay: 1,
        changeFirstDay: false,

    });

    function customRange(input) {
        var min = new Date(2008, 11 - 1, 1), //Set this to your absolute minimum date
            dateMin = min,
            dateMax = null,
            dayRange = 6; // Set this to the range of days you want to restrict to

        if (input.id === "StartDate") {
            if ($("#EndDate").datepicker("getDate") != null) {
                dateMax = $("#EndDate").datepicker("getDate");
                dateMin = $("#EndDate").datepicker("getDate");
                dateMin.setDate(dateMin.getDate() - dayRange);
                if (dateMin < min) {
                    dateMin = min;
                }
            }
            else {
                dateMax = new Date; //Set this to your absolute maximum date
            }
        }
        else if (input.id === "EndDate") {
            dateMax = new Date; //Set this to your absolute maximum date
            if ($("#StartDate").datepicker("getDate") != null) {
                dateMin = $("#StartDate").datepicker("getDate");
                var rangeMax = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(), dateMin.getDate() + dayRange);

                if (rangeMax < dateMax) {
                    dateMax = rangeMax;
                }
            }
        }
        return {
            minDate: dateMin,
            maxDate: dateMax
        };
    }
```

Comment: yes of course ,as i mentioned without the customRange function datepicker works fine by itself

Comment: sorry , its a script inside an asp.net mvc view

Comment: Yes, but is the jQuery execution happening after document has loaded? e.g. wrapped in `$(function(){ do my work here});`?

Comment: no , its not, if i try wrapping it in a function i get the same error from the very beginning and datepicker wont run even without the custom function

Comment: Is jQuery UI included?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/F9F28/ What is not working?

Answer (score 0):

If not already done (can't tell from your code), your jQuery should be wrapped in a document ready event to ensure it is run after the document is ready.

The newer syntax is:

### e.g.

```
 $(function(){
    $('#StartDate, #EndDate').datepicker({
        //dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        hourMin: 9,
        hourMax: 17,
        //minDate: '0',
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        beforeShow: customRange,
        firstDay: 1,
        changeFirstDay: false,

    });
  });
```

Otherwise the `beforeShow` triggers too early and nothing (including jQueryUI) is ready to be used.

This JSFiddle seems to work OK with your existing code (wrapped in startup):

### http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/F9F28/1/

Have you included your jQuery and jQuery UI in the correct order? (jQuery first).

Comment: still not working for me , i think there is something to do that i am running it in an asp.net mvc view

Comment: @Wizeman1986: If you are able to post a full HTML page of your output it should be easy to spot the problem. There is nothing special about running jQuery in MVC, as MVC is purely a HTML generator.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is not too late :-)

[this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx) link is very **useful**-